# Can't commit or push to github, and i didn't enable 2 factor authentication

Tags: linux, git, github

I get the error of "invalid username or password".

Also, I get the message that my authentication failed.

trying to push:

```
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/theseareprojects/testproject.git'
```

verifying remote:

```
origin  https://github.com/theseareprojects/testproject.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/theseareprojects/testproject.git (push)
```

verifying own info:

```
user.email=theseareprojects@protonmail.com
user.name=theseareprojects
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/theseareprojects/testproject.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

My info is correct...

Lol this kinda stucks, so thanks for the help. I didn't even enable 2 factor authentication. This has been puzzling me for quite a while now.

Comment: The error message you pasted doesn't say anything about authentication at all. It's complaining that you're trying to push a branch named `master` but you don't have one.

Comment: Are you on command line? At what stage do you get authentication error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+error%3A+src+refspec+master+does+not+match+any

Answer (score 0):

I think you've missed a commit. Try following step by step,

```
git add .
git commit -m "initial project commit"
git push origin master
```

However, you can also try the following as local reference independent solution if it's already committed. This signifies such you want to push the local `HEAD` ref to the remote `master` ref.

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```